# error while deploying omniscripts using github action pipeline

Tags: deployment, omniscript

im deploying multiple vesrions of same omniscripts from one org to another using meta data ,
but getting below while deploying . So want to know

1. whether can we deploy multiple versions of same omniscripts in one go (deployment).
2. or can you help how to resolve this error ..[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying omniscripts along with other metadata? If yes, try deploying them separately. So, deploy the non omniscript components first and then deploy omniscript components.